# How we can skip any Test Cases during CTS Run?

Tags: android, testing, cts

How we can do the following task:

During the running time we can skip the any package or case...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not skip the particular test cases directly in CTS. For that you have to execute the Test Cases manually which you want to execute. Since there are thousands of test cases so there is a short way to execute test cases, use the short package name which is common.

eg. you can use **$ start --plan CTS -p android.app** 
So this will executes all the test cases which starts with name android.app, like

android.app.cts.ActivityGroupTest 
android.app.cts.AlarmManagerTest
android.app.cts.AlertDialogTest
android.app.cts.InstrumentationTest
and so on...

Answer (score 2):

while running CTS locally we can actually write a `.xml` file (say `foo.xml`) which cab be kept under `android-cts/repository/plans` directory. Test cases under `<Entry exclude="class#method;class#method name="package"/>` will not be executed for the package.

And then we can run like below example

`cts run -s device_ip:port --plan foo`

This is helpful while debugging CTS issues

Answer (score 0):

We can skip the particular test case by editing the xml file in the Plans folder .
 For eg in the folder
         android-cts/repository/plans/CTS.xml

This contains list of all the packages to be executed.Simply delete the package which you want to exclude and save it with other name like
CTS_1.xml  and run.

> run cts --plan CTS1